# How do I get a collection of all products across all stores at once?

Tags: magento-enterprise

In Magento's admin panel, in the Catalog -> Manage Products section, it shows all the products across all the store views of your website.

I'd like to export this data - literally all of my products from every store - but I can't seem to access the data in an external PHP script.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect("id");
```

The above collection seems to contain only the products for my default store.

I've also tried adding `->addAttributeToFilter("website", array("in", array("1", "2", "3")))` etc. but this also does nothing to change the number of products.

Adding a store code into `Mage::app()` changes the result of the collection, but obviously I want **all** the products and not just a single store's.

I know this is possible because Magento itself does it under Manage Products - but how?

**TL;DR** I want a collection of **all** the products in my Magento installation from all stores. How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This will return data from all stores and store views as well.